# Would Al ions still be reducd to Al metal if it was aqueous soltion?

Tags: redox

To my knowledge, Aluminium is mostly mined in the form of Aluminium oxide or Al2O3 and then the Bayer process is used to extract and refine the pure Aluminium.

Now, The Al2O3 must be in a molten state when the process occurs. Why is that? Why must it be molten?

Also, Would the Al(3+) ions still be reduced to the Al metal if it was in an aqueous solution instead of being molten?

Thanks,

Comment: That's the problem - they wouldn't. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40199/why-cant-al3-be-reduced-to-solid-pure-aluminum

Comment: Ok. So, let me just clarify. Are you saying that Al3+ won't be reduced to pure Aluminium through the Bayer Process?

Comment: Al3+ can't be reduced in water, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The [Bayer process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_process) **does not** produce aluminium. It produces sodium aluminate, and finally aluminum oxide, which is later used in the [Hall–Héroult process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%E2%80%93H%C3%A9roult_process) (*without* water) to produce aluminium metal.

As @Mithoron implied, aluminium will displace the hydrogen from water, so cannot be made in an aqueous environment.